# Unix: recvfrom( )

Tags: c, unix, client

How to receive message from only desired client if I know that this client has been connected to my server?

```
recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFFSIZE, MSG_PEEK,
                (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &caddrlen);
```

addr will be  replaced by corresponding data, but I want receive data from only one client

Comment: Is this a UDP socket?

Comment: I use socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to receive message from only desired client if I know that this client has been connected to my server?

You can't really do this with a datagram socket in the `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` family, unless undesired clients are blocked at a lower level, such as via a firewall.  At least, not if you want to be able to continue to receive messages from desired clients after one from an undesired client arrives.  The network driver queues datagrams for you, and you need to handle them in order, where the C API for "handling" a datagram is to receive it via one of the several system calls that serve that purpose, such as `recvfrom()`.

You can discriminate between messages *after* receiving them, such as by discarding those from undesired clients.  However, it is of limited, special-purpose use to retrieve message data without dequeueing it, as the `MSG_PEEK` flag to `recvfrom()` provides.  In particular, that does not serve your stated purpose -- you will still need to receive every message, via a subsequent call that does not use `MSG_PEEK`.  Instead, I suggest simply reading the data via `recvfrom()`, checking the address to determine whether it's from the client you're interested in, and handling it appropriately.

If you want to handle multiple clients at the same time, then you have some alternatives.  A relatively simple one is to have a function, perhaps running in a dedicated thread, that receives all incoming messages and dispatches them appropriately according to their source addresses.  Another alternative is to open a new (datagram) socket for each client, each on its own port, and to set up a protocol by which you tell each client which port to use after their first contact.  Datagrams from unexpected clients on these additional ports would be erroneous, and therefore safe to reject.

Of course, the latter of those is an approximation to a connection-oriented protocol. If it seems attractive to you then perhaps you should be looking at stream sockets instead of datagram sockets.  Not only would that get you no-fuss client specificity, it would also provide for reliable and guaranteed in-order communication.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your response. But I don't full confirm to "discarding from undesired client". I think that gotten undesired messages will not be discarded by servere, because another client will desire to get his message. In the such situation process should ignore undesired message, but not discard. I will attach my resolution for my problem later

Comment: @AyratArifullin, read the answer again, especially the third and fourth paragraphs, starting with "If you want to handle multiple clients [...]."

Answer (score 2):

```
recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFFSIZE, MSG_PEEK,
                (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &caddrlen); 

if(addr.sin_addr.s_addr == "ADDRESS_OF_DESIRED_CLIENT")
{
//ALLOW USER
}
```

For IPV4 "addr.sin_addr.s_addr" is an int, but you can also get the Address in a string from.

Comment: How to remove desired message from queue?

Comment: I don't really understand you, if youre asking on how to process the request only once, then just create a state like

Comment: Do you know that MSG_PEEK don't allow remove messages from socket queue? Can you imagine such situation when server process call recvfrom in loop? Therefore, it can receive same message again. I assess your solution, but it isn't enhanced

Comment: There is one lack that after proccess corresponding message I can't remove it from server socket queue

Comment: I haven't use MSG_PEEK but maybe all you need to do is change the pointer of buf, I dont really know.